# Automorphisms of a free topological product

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, topological-groups, profinite-groups, free-groups

Let $G$, $G_1$, $G_2$ be Hausdorff topological groups. I am mainly interested in the case when those groups are profinite.
Let $G$ act continuously on $G_1$ and $G_2$ via continuous automorphisms, i.e. we have **continuous** maps $G \rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}_\mathrm{cont}(G_i)$ (with compact-open topology on $\mathrm{Aut}$'s).

From this one can define a map of **abstract** groups $$G \rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}_\mathrm{cont}(G_1 *_\mathrm{top} G_2),$$
where $*_\mathrm{top}$ denotes the free topological product. This can be done using the universal property of the free topological products and is given explicitly via formula ${}^g(g_1g_2g_1'g_2' \ldots g_1^{(m)}g_2^{(m)})={}^gg_1{}^gg_2{}^gg_1'{}^gg_2' \ldots {}^gg_1^{(m)}{}^gg_2^{(m)}$, where $g_1g_2g_1'g_2' \ldots g_1^{(m)}g_2^{(m)}$ is a word in $G_1 *_\mathrm{top} G_2$ (note that this makes sense as the underlying abstract group of $G_1 *_\mathrm{top} G_2$ is the usual free product of $G_1$ and $G_2$ as abstract groups).

**Question**: Is the above map continuous? If not, what would be some additional assumptions to make it continuous?